# G-d abrogated the Torah?

Tags: tanach, samuel-shmuel-book-of, bamidbar-numbers-book-of

I was having a discussion with some Muslims regarding abolishing of the Mosaic law. During that discussion they produced the following as an example of abrogation taking place:

[Bamidbar 25:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.25.13?lang=bi) states:

> וְהָ֤יְתָה לּוֹ֙ וּלְזַרְע֣וֹ אַחֲרָ֔יו בְּרִ֖ית כְּהֻנַּ֣ת עוֹלָ֑ם תַּ֗חַת אֲשֶׁ֤ר קִנֵּא֙ לֵֽאלֹהָ֔יו וַיְכַפֵּ֖ר עַל־בְּנֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל
>
> It shall be for him and his descendants after him a pact of priesthood for all time, because he took impassioned action for his God, thus making expiation for the Israelites.

Yet in [I Shmuel 2:30](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.2.30?lang=bi) the following is stated:

> לָכֵ֗ן נְאֻם־יְהוָה֮ אֱלֹהֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵל֒ אָמ֣וֹר אָמַ֔רְתִּי בֵּֽיתְךָ֙ וּבֵ֣ית אָבִ֔יךָ יִתְהַלְּכ֥וּ לְפָנַ֖י עַד־עוֹלָ֑ם וְעַתָּ֤ה נְאֻם־יְהוָה֙ חָלִ֣ילָה לִּ֔י כִּֽי־מְכַבְּדַ֥י אֲכַבֵּ֖ד וּבֹזַ֥י יֵקָֽלּוּ
>
> Assuredly—declares the LORD, the God of Israel—I intended for you and your father’s house to remain in My service forever. But now—declares the LORD—far be it from Me! For I honor those who honor Me, but those who spurn Me shall be dishonored.

In summary, their argument is that Shmuel abrogates Bamidbar.

How does one respond to this?

Comment: I don't see the contradiction. Eli's line wasn't the only line of Kohanim. The concept of Kohanim didn't end with this curse upon Eli's descendants. What's the issue?

Comment: Does it say anywhere that Eli was a descendant of Pinchas?

Comment: If G-d abrogated Torah, then what would Malachi 3:22 mean in regards to Torah?

Comment: @robev is right. The children of Eli are still kohanim. They were just punished for taking advantage of their position. If that is the best these Muslims can do it is pretty pathetic.

Comment: @robev Elijah was Pinchas according to some commentators.

Comment: Shmuel HaNavi is referring to those who spurned Him and His Torah at Mount Sinai, namely the descendants  of Eisav and Yishmael. All nations were given the opportunity to accept the Torah in fulfillment of the promise made to Avraham. This was also why Moshe insisted on including the erev rav. But the descendants  of Eisav and Yishmael rejected that offer.

Comment: @TurkHill indeed but irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @YaacovDeane The idea that G-d gave the nations an opportunity to accept Torah is only a metaphor.